# OpenGL Try to draw square but its display a rectangle

Tags: c, opengl

I try to draw a simple square by OpenGL but the result its display a rectangle. I guess that the problem is in the reshape function but I have no idea why (I'm new to OpenGL).

I what to keep aspect when I resize the window, that is not to stretch or shrink my image.

[image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z7It.png)

my reshape function

```
#define WINDOW_W 640
#define WINDOW_H 480

void reshape(int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0)
        height = 1;
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;

    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (width >= height)
       gluOrtho2D(0.0f, (GLdouble)WINDOW_W * aspect, (GLdouble)WINDOW_H, 0.0f);
    else
       gluOrtho2D(0.0f, (GLdouble)WINDOW_W, (GLdouble)WINDOW_H / aspect, 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

my draw function

```
void display(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // x=50 y=50 w=100 h=100 a square
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2i(50, 50);
        glVertex2i(50, 150);
        glVertex2i(150, 150);
        glVertex2i(150, 50);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your "square" will always be exactly 1.3333 (640 / 480) times as tall as it is wide, because while you do take the *actual* window size into account and compute the *actual* aspect ratio given the *actual* window size, you multiply that with `640` for the width and `480` for the height, for whatever reason.

And that won't work since that will *always* stretch your actual aspect ratio by a factor of 1.3333 making your square *always* 1.3333 as tall as it is wide.

To solve this, just multiply the arguments to the `gluOrtho2D()` call *with the same* value, depending on what the extent in your world space or "view space" should be for a square view space with a square aspect ratio.